# Delete Rows containing the String Excel Apache POI API

Tags: java, excel, api, apache-poi

My problem is that I want to delete all the rows that contain a String JUNI. I am successful doing this only on one row that contains this string my code that I have been using is:

```
  private void processExcelFile(File f_path) throws Exception{
    File path=f_path;

    try{

        FileInputStream is=new FileInputStream(path);

        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(is);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        int rowcount_post=0;
        int rowcount_304=0;

        for(Row row: sheet){
                    for(Cell cell : row){

                        if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){
                                if (cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().equals("JUNI")){

                                        rowcount_post=row.getRowNum();

                                        HSSFRow removingRow = sheet.getRow(rowcount_post);

                                            if (removingRow != null) {
                                            sheet.removeRow(removingRow);
                                            }



                                     try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:/juni.xls")) {
                                        wb.write(fileOut);
                                    }

                                }
                                else{
                                    System.out.print("NOT FOUND");

                                }



                        }

                    }
                }

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage(),"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

I just need to delete all the rows in my Excel file that contains this string JUNI.How can i do like this please help me I have been trying my best since last 3 days~Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. This will remove all of the rows of the sheet, in which any cell contains "JUNI" as its sub-string.

```
    public static void test(XSSFSheet sheet){
       XSSFRow Row = null;
       XSSFCell Cell = null;
       int LastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
       for(int RowNum= 0;RowNum<LastRowNum-1;RowNum++){
            Row=sheet.getRow(RowNum);
            for(int CellNum = 0; CellNum<Row.getLastCellNum();CellNum++){
               Cell = Row.getCell(CellNum);
               String TextInCell=Cell.toString();
               if(TextInCell.contains("JUNI")){
                  sheet.shiftRows(RowNum+1, LastRowNum, -1);
                  LastRowNum--;
                  RowNum--;
                  break;
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is not deleting the empty rows inside my excel file please can you tell me i want to delete the empty rows and then write a new file!

Comment: sry I had not understand you Question exactly. Now I have updated the code. Please try that.

Comment: THANKS I HAVE ALREADY DONE WITH IT ANYHOW THANKS FOR YOUR HELP! I GOT AN IDEA FROM YOUR HELP REALLY